# Redmine 0.9 on subdomain, (redmine.mydomain.com instead of redmine.mydomain.com/redmine)

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, redmine

I would like to acces to redmine with this url redmine.mydomain.com instead of redmine.mydomain.com/redmine. How can I do it please?

Here is my .conf apache of redmine

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName redmine.mydomain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   <Directory /var/www/html>
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/html/redmine>
      Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
   RailsBaseURI /redmine
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName redmine.mydomain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine/public

   <Directory /var/www/html/redmine/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>

   RailsBaseURI /
   RailsEnv production

</VirtualHost>
```

Oh, and be sure in Redmine's Administration page you point it at the proper url, otherwise it won't generate links correctly...